# How to fade out and replace word with CSS animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make a CSS animation were a word fades out, another words replaces it and the new word fades in. Can't seem to figure out the correct way to do it. Here's my code:

HTML

```
<span class="words"></span>
```

CSS

```
.words:before {
    content: "one";
    animation-name: replacement;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes replacement {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        content: "two";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fp2h6q4L/

Answer (score 2):

Try this CSS

```css
.words:before {

  opacity:0;
 content: "one";
 animation-name: replacement;
 animation-duration: 4s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-out;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: absolute;
}

@keyframes replacement {
 0%{
  opacity: 1;
 }
  50%{
    opacity:0;
  }
  100%{
    content:"two";
    opacity:1;
  }


}
```

```html
<span class="words"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with pure CSS, you'll probably need to define a second animation to change the text and then set the delay on that one to run when opacity is 0 so that the abrupt change is hidden.